# How to allow only Photo viewing when using pickImage in Android app Flutter development

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Thank you for taking time out of your busy schedule to browse this page.

We are currently developing an Android application in Flutter.
I am currently developing an Android application using Flutter, and I am using pickImage to retrieve photos from internal storage.
pickImage is used for the photo acquisition process from the internal storage.
However, when I tap the button on the Android side, it selects a folder instead of a photo.
I am afraid that I can browse the folder without permission confirmation.

I would like to know if there is a way to browse only Photo when using pickImage.
If this is not possible, I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to check the permissions of the folder.

```
final image =
        await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 20);
```

Comment: `am afraid that I can browse the folder without permission confirmation.` Well be glad you can. Why bother the user with confirming?

Comment: And photos are ordered in folders. What do you have against some order?

Comment: I am not opposed to it,
I am in a state of discomfort with being able to check all folders, even though I only want to browse folders of photos.

Comment: You never said that those folders did not contain fotos. So what do they contain?

Comment: And you cannot select folders i think. Only files.